# How do i stop these gaps from appearing when re-sizing an image grid?

Tags: css

Is there a way to make the other images in the image grid automatically move and fill these gaps shown in the image linked below. When my web browser is full screen there are no issues but when I start to change the size of the browser some gaps in the grid start to appear.

Thanks in advance.

This is my css

```
.grid{
  display:grid;
  gap:0.5rem;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,minmax(200px,1fr));
  grid-auto-rows:300px;
}
.card{
  height:100%; 
  width:100%;
  border-radius:10px;
  background-size:cover;
  background-image:center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .card-tall {
    grid-row: span 2 / auto;
  }

  .card-wide {
    grid-column: span 2 / auto;
  }
}
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="card card-wide" style="background-image: url(photos/1image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card" style="background-image: url(photos/2image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card" style="background-image: url(photos/3image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card card-wide" style="background-image: url(photos/5image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card" style="background-image: url(photos/6image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card-tall card" style="background-image: url(photos/7image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card card-tall" style="background-image: url(photos/9image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card" style="background-image: url(photos/10image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card card-tall" style="background-image: url(photos/11image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card card-wide" style="background-image: url(photos/12image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card card-tall" style="background-image: url(photos/13image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card" style="background-image: url(photos/14image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card" style="background-image: url(photos/15image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card card-tall" style="background-image: url(photos/16image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card card-tall" style="background-image: url(photos/17image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card card-tall" style="background-image: url(photos/18image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card card-tall" style="background-image: url(photos/19image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card" style="background-image: url(photos/20image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card card-tall" style="background-image: url(photos/21image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card card-tall" style="background-image: url(photos/22image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card " style="background-image: url(photos/23image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card" style="background-image: url(photos/24image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card" style="background-image: url(photos/4image.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="card card-wide" style="background-image: url(photos/8image.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3wTA.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hPFi.jpg

Comment: You can obtaine the desired output using masonry (a js library) i thin you cant only with css [https://css-tricks.com/first-steps-into-a-possible-css-masonry-layout/](https://css-tricks.com/first-steps-into-a-possible-css-masonry-layout/)

Comment: try to add `grid-auto-flow: dense;` CSS rule. You can see my similar example here https://meetup-shuffler.stackblitz.io (click on `Get attendees` button)

Comment: @Andriy Thank you so much, using "grid-auto-flow: dense;" solved my problem instantly.

Comment: I am glad it helped you, I will post it as my answer for future references, please accept my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try just to add 'grid-auto-flow: dense;' CSS rule:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px,1fr));
  grid-auto-rows:300px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense; /* <--- THIS RULE ADDED */
}
```

see my [similar example](https://meetup-shuffler.stackblitz.io/) for example